# Core Data Architecture

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am working on an iOS application on which the Core Data was already implemented. So I couldn't understand the Core Data implementations from the scratch. But I could work on Core Data while adding new features. But I am having many doubts on Core Data. I couldn't find out a clear idea from any of the blog.

1) **Question 1 -** I have setup the architecture for application in a way that it has a Webservice controller class, Webservice helper class, DatabaseManager class, UiViewController classes and Model Objects as part of Core Data.

Web service controller makes the connection to service with NSURLConnection and other related functionalities. Once the response got from web service, it gives a callback to Webservice helper class with blocks.

Web service handler class helps to call the services from all the UIViewControllers. Web service helper class acts as an intermediate class to make web services between UIViewControllers and Web service controller. So when the web service helper gets the callback from  web service controller, it sends the response back to UIViewController with the help of blocks.

**My question is here, What should be flow of storing the web service response in to core data as well as updating the data in the UI. I would like to know the best practice for doing it. Should I save the data in to core data, then retrieve and display in the UI? But saving the data will take time if the data is big. Should core data operation and updating the UI synchronously.**

2) **Question 2 -** I read about Core data operation concurrency in many blogs, still I am not pretty much clear about the concurrency in Core Data.

According to my knowledge, inorder to achieve concurrency, we have to create two managedobjectcontext, one with NSMainQueueConcurrencyType and other NSPrivateQueueConcurrency. Then all the save and update operations has to be executed in privateMOC[NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType] and read can be executed with mainMOC[NSMainQueueConcurrencyType]. How this operation is related with performBlock?

3) **Question 3 -** As we can create multiple moc, should that be of NSConfinementConcurrencyType and execute performBlock on all doc for concurrency?

4) **Question 4** - What is difference of implementing concurrency as mentioned in Question 2 & Question 3?

5) **Question 5 -** Consider, I am reading a record using core data and due to concurrency the same record has to update a value. How this situation can be handled. What I know here is that I have to use the merge policy. But I am not sure how to implement this, since I am not clear about the above cases.

6) **Question 6 -** In an application, how many managedobjectcontext can be created of type NSMainQueueConcurrencyType, NSConfinementConcurrencyType and NSPrivateQueueCOncurrencyType?

Can anyone answer the above questions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Am not so much aware of concurrency but, am currently working on the same kind of situation you have and i found managing all manually easy. I have created one database object and one server object for a single model. And am managing received response from server and saving those in database when response is coming from server. And when user is in offline am just fetching the data from DB and displaying it. I started working on this pattern that's why i got this easy but i don't prefer this. You first try any alternate way. If no way found you can prefer this.

Answer (score 2):

This really should be several separate questions.  I will attempt to answer the architecture question, and perhaps touch on some of the others.

The return path from the web service should not reach any view controllers directly.  The point where your service helper has parsed the response and validated it is where you want to save to core data.  This task should be handed off to another class.

From the view controller side, you want to use `NSFetchedResultsController`s (FRCs) to know when the model has changed.  You can setup an FRC to watch any number of objects, including a single object.

FRCs were intended for table views, and there are numerous examples available on how to use them for that purpose.  If you have a view where you are editing a single object and you use the web service to save updates, for example, you can have an FRC that is watching the edited object.  When the save is complete, the FRC will trigger and you can update the UI to indicate success, or whatever.

**Core Data**

Core Data concurrency is not trivial, as you've discovered.  I've had the best experience with the following setup:

- A read-only context with `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`.  This is the initial context that is tied to the persistent store.  This context remains for the entire session.
- An `NSOperationQueue` with a concurrency of 1.  Operations on this queue clone the main (read-only) context with a concurrency type of `NSConfinementConcurrencyType`, and are connected to the same store.  Only these cloned contexts are allowed to save.  These contexts are discarded when the operation is complete.
- A merge handler that will merge changes into the main context.

Operations execute on background threads, and are synchronous with respect to each other.  This makes merges simple.  Cloned contexts are setup with a merge policy of `NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy`, and the main context with `NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy`.

View controllers, and other main-thread activities, use the main context, which always exists.

There are lots of other setups, including multiple, writeable siblings, parent-child relationships, etc.  I recommend picking something simple, because you don't want to be fighting Core Data *and* threading issues at the same time.

I recommend watching [this video](https://vimeo.com/89370886) by Paul Goracke.  The inspiration for my preferred stack was taken directly from Paul's presentation.

Comment: Thanks Avi for responding to my question. NSFetchedResultsControllers can only be used for TableView, otherwise how the callback can be given to UIViewControllers. I heard about the notification from core data. But I never felt that as a feasible solution, since the notification fired for all the core data operation. Do u have any other feasible suggestion for this.

Comment: Avi, Can we use any other database other than Sqlite with core data?

Comment: I have used FRCs without tableviews or collection views many times.  I am not sure what you mean that they can't be used independently.  I have even used them on background threads.  I am not sure which notification you are referring to.  The notification for which you need a merge handler is triggered on context saves.  I don't understand what the issue would be with merging every save.

Comment: You may be able to find a third-party subclass that provides a persistent store for some other database, but I don't know of any.  In any event, what other database will you have available in an iOS app?

Comment: Thanks Avi for the information. i will try out the ways that you have explained.